# Compute cartesian product of N sets such that no resulting tuples are commutative

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

The task is to find an analytical solution to the following problem:
Given `N` arbitrary sets compute their Cartesian product in such a way that every resulting tuple is not commutative to any other. Basically make sure that for any tuple you receive, no matter how you rearrange its elements you will not get any other tuple.

I'm sorry for not being able to express this in math notation, I'm very much not a mathematician. This problem is meant to solve a more concrete [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77137588/17948216)

At the very least I can give an example:

Consider `A = {1, 2, 3}; B = {1, 2}; C = {7, 8, 9}`. We're looking for `D = f(A, B, C)` where

```
D = 
(1, 1, 7)
(1, 1, 8)
(1, 1, 9)
(1, 2, 7)
(1, 2, 8)
(1, 2, 9)
(2, 2, 7)
(2, 2, 8)
(2, 2, 9)
(3, 1, 7)
(3, 1, 8)
(3, 1, 9)
(3, 2, 7)
(3, 2, 8)
(3, 2, 9)
```

`D` has 15 tuples (out of the possible 18) because the other 3 (for example `(2, 1, 7)` is commutative to `(1, 2, 7)` and therefore needs to be discarded.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "analytical solution"? An algorithm to obtain all such tuples?

Comment: @jd27 Yes, an algorithm would be good.

Comment: Are elements of one set distincts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$D(\{A_i\}_i) = \{(a_0, \dots, a_n)\,|\, \forall i, a_i \in A_i \, \land \, \forall i<j, (a_i,a_j)\in S(A_i,A_j) \Longrightarrow a_i < a_j \}$$

with $$S(A,B) = \{(a,b) \,|\, a,b \in A\cap B \land a \ne b\} $$

Note it is exponential and it likely requires additional work if you allow elements in a set to be identical.